# Prove : $\tan \alpha_1<(\sin \alpha_1+\cdots+\sin \alpha_n)/(\cos \alpha_1+\cdots+\cos \alpha_n)<\tan \alpha_n$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, fractions

> If $0<\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\cdots<\alpha_n<\frac{\pi}{2}$ is given 
>   then prove: 
>   $$\tan\alpha_1 < \frac{\sin\alpha_1+\sin\alpha_2+\sin\alpha_3+\cdots+\sin\alpha_n}{\cos\alpha_1+\cos\alpha_2+\cos\alpha_3+\cdots+\cos\alpha_n} < \tan\alpha_n$$

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te left inequality.

We need to prove that
$$\frac{\sin\alpha_1}{\cos\alpha_1}<\frac{\sin\alpha_1+\cdots+\sin{\alpha_n}}{\cos\alpha_1+\cdots+\cos\alpha_n}$$ or
$$\sin(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)+\cdots+\sin(\alpha_1-\alpha_n)<0,$$
which is obvious.

We can prove the right inequality by the same way.

Finally we'll get there
$$\sin(\alpha_n-\alpha_1)+\cdots+\sin(\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1})>0.$$
Done!

Comment: I don't really understand

Comment: I am in 11th standard and this was given in our exam. Noone really solved.  It will be very helpful if you explain it

Comment: @Pragna I used $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta$.

Comment: Ok yes... I understand

Comment: @ Pragna You are welcome!